# Name of type of curve that uses x value as a divisor for y

Tags: curves

What is (or is there) a name of a curve that is on X and Y axis, where the Y value is divided by X?

For example, Y at X being 1 = 100, Y at 2 = 100/2 Y at 3 = 100/3. The type of curve I am thinking of would have Y any start value where X is 1, and the subsequent steps of X will divide Y.  Another example with a different start value could be Y at 150 = 150, Y at 2 = 150/2 etc.

Comment: I would say that 'y is inversely proportional to x'. If $y=\frac{k}{x}$ then one says that $y$ is inversely proportional to $x$ and $k$ is the constant of proportionality.

Comment: The curve itself is called a [rectangular hyperbola](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbola#Rectangular_hyperbola); if you want to describe the relationship, f coppens' comment is a good choice.

Comment: @fcoppens can you make that an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that it has to do with 'proportionality'/'inverse proportionality'.

When, for some constant $k$ we have that $y=kx$ the one says that $y$ is **(directly) proportional** to $x$ and $k$ is called the constant of proportionality.

In a similar way, if, for some constant $k$, it holds that $y=\frac{k}{x}$,  then one says that $y$  is **inversely proportional** to $x$  and $k$  is the constant of proportionality.